# How to connect AWS IOT by using AT Command (Sim7020C)

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, gsm, at-command, aws-iot

Does anyone know how to use AT Command to connect AWS IOT(Sim7020C)?

It's my log below, I have tried so many times and all responses are OK.
So I really can't tell what's wrong with my commands...
I think something went wrong in Certification step, but I'm not sure

```
AT+GSV

SIMCOM_Ltd
SIM7020C
Revision:1752B12SIM7020C

OK
AT+CGCONTRDP

+CGCONTRDP: 1,5,"internet.iot","10.173.155.29.255.255.255.0",,"168.95.1.1","168.95.192.1",,,,,1500

OK
AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 9,0

OK
AT+CSETCA=0,1172,1,0,-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n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OK
AT+CSETCA=0,1172,0,0,VT8QtPHRh8jrdkPSHCa2XV4cdFyQzR1bldZwgJcJmApzyMZFo6IQ6XU
5MsI+yMRQ+hDKXJioaldXgjUkK642M4UwtBV8ob2xJNDd2ZhwLnoQdeXeGADbkpy
rqXRfboQnoZsG4q5WTP468SQvvG5
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

OK

AT+CSETCA=1,1208,1,0,-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n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OK
AT+CSETCA=1,1208,0,0,Lu+QtxR2Ij2Wv9iSLlkjAZWeppVCeJT/GMQ+SPHdt98Ry3Yj8XOJwCB
yXK00k3oiR81gnGTtZStAb5VC6KflLOKdPR9ZuXmYbSxdj5U/+Z//c1OmHBjfXlM
oG01qOwG1Sx1LmBsi1AkyJy0wPh9LW46qSRWHFuFFKafke0OqhqlKArTdAuP7A==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

OK
AT+CSETCA=2,1658,1,0,-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA4eBij7jIG34/+LicstRtMmAzL2nrRTuPI1McMdPGfVJHx14a
sAsrLixTQFm2JTXVrlOlIaM65zUZCFHyrqxmfGFherytybl3ci588mqAt+S6X/H4
kzFAcx7qNDgdR7J69mv8H3LO/s5d5oVzTZO8nAF5ZBsDQTfRt5ujjEpZSgFSaaTv
+aUyonXRGEbVbpA1OBR60lumUrYMdPlqAsKGGsLA3AAuFE3puRJWms1KwzXbT55W
QH6r8MXoyv0QlZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ5nps1aybpPpaLU0wr
w/0s033nQqwHBPdemqC+3GVRlPEyCEc4sGHICwIDAQABAoIBAQCtZx1DSJAWyy1B
PDjP8NSDv+aLl7zOQZL5g2w5tGLFAs2n+E50p55WrCCdXkG+/z0zv3MeB7nIlbLJ
+F9eSWvEQN4c44xnOMLCHX4+fBSlGCscTR6PoVfhCPKzdADGcfaEBxJe8jyG0Na1
ie2iuLAq89bFSxeMkdWmJw2/PbSeYkQY2D0Y5lf0cNofkOKoVbmkDX2ujPScImHq
NFRk9reliJqL4APfn7qCx054/XN2Ven+0yhZo9yx70p4swwwsGXdsuxAYBG/8aeT
V/3BAGnFrT2MGO5HeKYwcKW5z+xOmT0+5rxneCu3aEXdcPLQoliKsg747pwOdQxT
rWqxP/LBAoGBAPZIWiryCS9F2u7uOhinspMOAH/cLp/ZpREHdRcjTHzrBiM8iAud
vgSR/UgSTax2NugUlSDiEXEZgSwFM1wZxGBOontXChxHHCEKprH5ZgU5vANax7vF
Z99v2I+GUMOjSNR7wgigaQj5ZQhxSgO7mGJFY2KO/UU2JIkdBuOlUBJVAoGBAOrJ
6jm6X2XGUHruhbRNw3MO+Obp6PLjRf3D8dR5ZTNq7Amsr4lpEfCedrQ+7D1xIsUL
wAX2c

OK
AT+CSETCA=2,1658,0,0,S/SHohiUKlEJB8Qdc5e192/nkeYHTYcBhj3UgprxMWl94T1iJxQwpOu5Uim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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

OK
AT+CSETCA?

Root CA:166

Client CA:84

Client Private Key:92

OK
AT+CMQNEW="example-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",8883,12000,1024

+CMQNEW: 0

OK
AT+CMQCON=0,3,"CLIENTID",12000,1,0

OK
AT+CMQCON?

+CMQCON: 0,1,example-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

OK
AT+CMQSUB=0,"TEST",0

OK

AT+CMQPUB=0,"TEST",1,0,0,8,"31323334"

OK


------------------------------------------------------------------
This is an example format from Simcom

AT+CSETCA=0,1172,1,0,"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n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"

ERROR

------------------------------------------------------------------
This is another format that I tried

AT+CSETCA=0,1172,1,0,"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
"MIIDQTCCAimgAwIBAgITBmyfz5m/jAo54vB4ikPmljZbyjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF\n"
"ADA5MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEPMA0GA1UEChMGQW1hem9uMRkwFwYDVQQDExBBbWF6\n"
"b24gUm9vdCBDQSAxMB4XDTE1MDUyNjAwMDAwMFoXDTM4MDExNzAwMDAwMFowOTEL\n"
"MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDzANBgNVBAoTBkFtYXpvbjEZMBcGA1UEAxMQQW1hem9uIFJv\n"
"b3QgQ0EgMTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALJ4gHHKeNXj\n"
"ca9HgFB0fW7Y14h29Jlo91ghYPlXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOsqTQNroBvo3bSMgHFzZM\n"
"9O6II8c+6zf1tRn4SWiw3te5djgdYZ6k/oI2peVKVuRF4fn9tBb6dNqcmzU5L/qw\n"
"IFAGbHrQgLKm+a/sRxmPUDgH3KKHOVj4utWp+UhnMJbulHheb4mjUcAwhmahRWa6\n"
"VOujw5H5SNz/0egwLX0tdHA114gk957EWW67c4cX8jJGKLhD+rcdqsq08p8kDi1L\n"
"93FcXmn/6pUCyziKrlA4b9v7LWIbxcceVOF34GfID5yHI9Y/QCB/IIDEgEw+OyQm\n"
"jgSubJrIqg0CAwEAAaNCMEAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMC\n"
"AYYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFIQYzIU07LwMlJQuCFmcx7IQTgoIMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA\n"
"A4IBAQCY8jdaQZChGsV2USggNiMOruYou6r4lK5IpDB/G/wkjUu0yKGX9rbxenDI\n"
"U5PMCCjjmCXPI6T53iHTfIUJrU6adTrCC2qJeHZERxhlbI1Bjjt/msv0tadQ1wUs\n"
"N+gDS63pYaAC\n"

OK
```

SIM7020 Series_MQTT(S)_Application Note_V1.05
(https://m5stack.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/resource/docs/datasheet/unit/nbiot/SIM7020%20Series_MQTT(S)_Application%20Note_V1.05.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0qMLRTFa6GIcURLV6OoxFoqd-T-05d0rojXjLvoUug6hvomkBONUD7-Dc)

SIM7020 Series_MQTT(S)_Application Note_V1.03
(https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/7/7b/SIM7020_Series_MQTT%28S%29_Application_Note_V1.03.pdf)